# How do I allocate an array in an OpenGL fragment shader?

Tags: opengl-es

Here is the fragment shader code I am trying to use (in OpenGL ES 2.0, OpenGLES GLSL ES 1.00):

```
GLchar strFragmentShader[] =  
"precision mediump float;                                              \n"
"varying vec2 vTexCoord;                                               \n"
"uniform sampler2D sTexture;                                           \n"
"uniform float offset[] = float[]( 0.0000, 1.3846, 3.2307);            \n"
"uniform float weight[] = float[]( 0.2270, 0.3162, 0.0702);            \n"
"void main()                                                           \n"
"{                                                                     \n"
"  vec4 sum = texture2D( sTexture, vec2(vTexCoord)/1024.0)*weight[0];  \n"
"  for (int i=0;i<3;i++) {                                                                 \n"
"    sum += texture2D( sTexture, ( vec2(vTexCoord+vec2(0.0,offset[i])/1024.0 )*weight[i];  \n"
"    sum += texture2D( sTexture, ( vec2(vTexCoord-vec2(0.0,offset[i])/1024.0 )*weight[i];  \n"
"  }                                                                                       \n"  
"  gl_FragColor = sum;                                                 \n"
"}                                                                     \n";
```

I am basically following the examples on [this page](http://rastergrid.com/blog/2010/09/efficient-gaussian-blur-with-linear-sampling/), but I get `ERROR:LEX/PARSE-1 (fragment shader, line 4) Syntax error`.

If I try to declare them as `const` rather than `uniform` as suggested [here](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Data_Type_%28GLSL%29) (under Array Constructors), I get `ERROR:CUSTOM-5 (fragment shader, line 4) Array cannot be const`.

Obviously lines 4 and 5 will have the same problem. How do I get this to compile? What is the correct syntax?

Comment: It seems to me that in that specific case you could use vec3 instead.Otherwise, I think you need to specify the size in the array definition: uniform float offset[3]; and not give it a constructor, just bind it in your drawing code.

Comment: Why did you rollback the edit? GLSL was written against the OpenGL 1.5 spec., but it neither ships with OpenGL 1.5 nor has anything to do with this question. `precision` is meaningless in OpenGL, so this shader *must* be GLES-related. GLSL for OpenGL and GLSL for OpenGL ES actually have two separate specifications, which is why it is important to tag GLSL-related questions appropriately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that this is just a limitation of GLES. It can't be done. An alternative method needs to be found.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it like this:

```
GLchar strFragmentShader[] =  
"precision mediump float;                                              \n"
"varying vec2 vTexCoord;                                               \n"
"uniform sampler2D sTexture;                                           \n"
"void main()                                                           \n"
"{ 
"   vec3 offset = vec3(0.0000, 1.3846, 3.2307);            \n"
"   vec3 weight = vec3( 0.2270, 0.3162, 0.0702);            \n"                                                                    \n"
"  vec4 sum = texture2D( sTexture, vec2(vTexCoord)/1024.0)*weight[0];  \n"
"  for (int i=0;i<3;i++) {                                                                 \n"
"    sum += texture2D( sTexture, ( vec2(vTexCoord+vec2(0.0,offset[i])/1024.0 )*weight[i];  \n"
"    sum += texture2D( sTexture, ( vec2(vTexCoord-vec2(0.0,offset[i])/1024.0 )*weight[i];  \n"
"  }                                                                                       \n"  
"  gl_FragColor = sum;                                                 \n"
"}"
```

or this if you need it passed to the shader as a uniform:

```
GLchar strFragmentShader[] =  
"precision mediump float;                                              \n"
"varying vec2 vTexCoord;                                               \n"
"uniform sampler2D sTexture;                                           \n"
"uniform vec3 offset;                                                    \n"
"uniform  vec3 weight;                                                  \n" 
"void main()                                                           \n"
"{                                                                    \n"
"  vec4 sum = texture2D( sTexture, vec2(vTexCoord)/1024.0)*weight[0];  \n"
"  for (int i=0;i<3;i++) {                                                                 \n"
"    sum += texture2D( sTexture, ( vec2(vTexCoord+vec2(0.0,offset[i])/1024.0 )*weight[i];  \n"
"    sum += texture2D( sTexture, ( vec2(vTexCoord-vec2(0.0,offset[i])/1024.0 )*weight[i];  \n"
"  }                                                                                       \n"  
"  gl_FragColor = sum;                                                 \n"
"}"
```

or use `uniform float[n]` where `n` is the desired (constant) size in the second example if you need an array, or `const float[n]` in the first example if you need an array and you don't want to pass the value from your C++ code.

Comment: A vec3 cannot be accessed from within a loop by index. I'm actually not passing these from the program they really are consts and that code makes more sense to me, but it doesnt matter whether `const float offset[3]` is inside `main` or not. I get the same error.

Comment: @Octopus: Actually, generally speaking this boils down to being unable to index an array by a `non-const` expression (loop indices are lumped under a separate less restrictive category called `const-index` expressions). It applies not only to vectors but scalars (`float` arrays) as well. The thing is, this behavior is not guaranteed - some implementations may provide it, but none are **required** to provide it. See: A.5 and 10.34 [here](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/specs/2.0/GLSL_ES_Specification_1.0.17.pdf)

Comment: @Andon, indeed it seems to be a limitation. If you provide this as an answer I can select it as accepted.